# Prepending generated audio silence when merging audio w/ non-zero starting PTS and video with zero-based PTS for equal duration, aligned streams

Tags: ffmpeg

When extracting segments from a media file with video and audio streams without re-encoding (-c copy), it is likely that the requested seek & end time specified will not land precisely on a keyframe in the source.

In this case, ffmpeg will grab the nearest keyframe of each track and position them with differing starting PTS values so that they remain in sync.

Video keyframes tend to be a lot more spaced apart, so you can often end up with something like this:

[image]

Viewing the clip in VLC, the audio will start at 5 seconds in.

However, in other video players or video editors I've noticed this can lead to some playback issues or a/v desync.

A solution would be to re-encode both streams when extracting the clip, allowing ffmpeg to precisely seek to the specified seek time and generating equal length & synced audio and video tracks.

However, in my case I do not want to re-encode the video, it is costly and produces lower quality video and/or greater file sizes. I would prefer to only re-encode the audio, filling the initial gap with generated silence.

This should be simple, but everything I've tried has failed to generate silence before the audio stream begins.

I've tried apad, aresample=sync=1, and using amerge to combine the audio with anullsrc. None of it works.

All I can think to possibly get around this is to use ffprobe on the misaligned source to retrieve the first audio PTS, and in a second ffmpeg process apply this value as a negative -itoffset, then concatting the audio track with generated silence lasting the duration of silence... But surely there's a better way, with just one instance of ffmpeg?

Any ideas?

Comment: Provide the actual command tried, and ideally the input file.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled across the solution by trying some more things.
I take the misaligned source media and process it with another ffmpeg instance with some audio filters:

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i input.mkv -c copy -c:a aac -af apad,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0 -ac 2 -shortest -y output.mkv
```

And it does exactly what I want, pads the beginning (and end) of the audio stream with silence making the audio stream equal length to the video.

The only drawback is that I can't combine this with my original ffmpeg command that extracts the clip, the only way this works is as a 2-step process.